# Property Inspections on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, real-estate

Hypothetically, if a Jew wanted to sell his home. Would the real estate agent be able to organise property inspections on Saturday?

Notes: The Jew would not be contacted during Shabbos. The Jew would not be present on Shabbos (lets assume the property is vacant and the Jewish family have moved out).

Comment: Interesting. There is a whole literature on asking a non-Jew to do *melacha* on Shabbat. Generally it is permitted if you don't specify the work has to be done on Shabbat and if the non-Jew decides to do it then for his own benefit. It would only work for a non-Jewish real estate agent of course. Of course for any real application, you would want to ask your Rav. The practical halacha might depend whether there are issues of chilul Hashem involved, e.g., if the house was in a Jewish area, with possibly Jewish buyers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is *maryis ayin*, that Jewish onlookers will get the wrong idea. (I'm assuming this is a realtor's "open house" with a big crowd, vs. one inspector who drives up in their regular car, walks in, looks around, and leaves. The latter really doesn't look like much.)

Anyhow -- back to the realtor open house case: [Rabbi Daniel Mann cites Orchos Shabbos 23:158, who prohibits.](https://www.torahmusings.com/2022/06/an-agent-showing-a-house-on-shabbat/)

To paraphrase his argument: Clearly I'm not paying the realtor specifically to do anything on shabbos; they get paid "to sell the house, however." The Mishna Brurah 252:17 is still concerned that the onlookers will think I directed him specifically to do work on shabbos, because it's my house.

It wouldn't surprise me if there are contemporary opinions arguing that today, everyone knows the realtor was just told "sell this house however" and not directed in any way vis-a-vis Shabbos; but I haven't seen such a source per se.